# What is a "single grid stack", relating to raster data?

Tags: python, rasterstack

I created a boosted regression tree model using data points from a DEM, TPI, and land cover raster. However, I'm having problems finding resources that describe how to fit my trained model over those rasters. I found a few examples of this using R but my model was created in Python.

I found this website: http://www.wvview.org/open_source_gis/site_renders/Spatial_ML/site/index.html#predict-to-raster-data

This is actually what I'm trying to do but I don't understand what is meant by "I have generally found that it is easier to feed in the predictor variables as a single grid stack, which is prepared using GIS software, to avoid any issues with cell misalignment or different numbers of rows and columns. Python is generally not robust to dealing with these issues."

How does one "stack" rasters together to make a single grid stack which can be imported into Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a composite raster is the same thing as a "grid stack". After making a composite of 3 different raster layers I was able to access each layer using a package called `Pyspatialml` in order to perform the boosted regression tree analysis.